# Navigation bar not sitting in menu properly

Tags: html, css

I'm new to HTML and CSS and am trying to make a menu bar. I placed a navigation bar inside a div assuming that it would kind of be in the center. Instead, it appears to sit on the bottom. Also, how could I position the navigation bar so it's not just floating to the left or the right.

Side question, how can I have it so the menu bar completely extends to the edge of the screen. Like the one at the top of this site.

Here's the code:

```css
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}
#nav {
  background-color: white;
  height: 300px;
  width: auto;
  height: 55px;
  box-shadow: 1px 3px 2px #888888;
}
h1 {
  color: #35e3c1;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 900;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  color: #1fe0ba;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
}
li a:hover {
  color: #1abc9c;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Soycial</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="nav">
    <h1>Soycial</h1>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

I have added `margin:0;` to the `ul`.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}
#nav {
  background-color: white;
  height: 300px;
  width: auto;
  height: 55px;
  box-shadow: 1px 3px 2px #888888;
}
h1 {
  color: #35e3c1;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 900;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  color: #1fe0ba;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
}
li a:hover {
  color: #1abc9c;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Soycial</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="nav">
    <h1>Soycial</h1>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Other ways this could have been done would have by messing with top and bottom margins(depending on what specific ratios you want). Using this way will get you specifically what alignment you want vertically.